# What is the best way to authenticate the same user from the same database but the different applications (e.g. Django and Node js)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, django, amazon-ec2, rest

1. I have created a registration and login system in **Django 3.0** framework. In the backend, I am using the MYSQL database.
   And it is running on **EC2-instance-1**.
2. There is a **Nodejs** script running on the other **EC2-instance-2**. Connected to MYSQL database which is hosted on **EC2-instance-1**

So, I have registered a user from the **Django** app and I also can authenticate that user.
But when I try to authenticate the same user from Node js Script connected to the same database it won't work.

What is the best way to authenticate the same user from the same database but the different applications (e.g. Django and node js)?

Comment: *authenticate the same user from the same database but the different application* Noway. Each connection to DBMS is separate and independent.

Comment: *when I try to authenticate the same user from Node js Script connected to the same database it won't work.* Of course - username is the same, but userhost differs.

Comment: @Akina is it not possible??

Comment: MySQL authentication is fully internal and inaccessible. I doubt that it is possible.